# php strtotime('this monday') shows date of coming week

Tags: php, strtotime

I want to get Monday-Friday using the `strtotime` function. I have used ```strtotome('this monday') which gives me Monday of coming week when I pass today's date (today is Friday). This suppose to give me Monday of ongoing week

I get correct date only when $date is coming from weekInput

```
$weekInput = $request->input('week');
$weekInput = str_replace("-","", $weekInput);

if($request->input('week')) {
  $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2021W34"));
} else {
  $date = date('Y-m-d');
}

$monday = Date('Y-m-d', (strtotime('this monday', strtotime($date))));
$tuesday = date('Y-m-d', (strtotime('this tuesday', strtotime($date))));
$wednesday = date('Y-m-d', (strtotime('this wednesday', strtotime($date))));
$thursday = date('Y-m-d', (strtotime('this thursday', strtotime($date))));
$friday = date('Y-m-d', (strtotime('this friday', strtotime($date))));
```

Comment: What to do if today is Monday I am getting current week Monday? I cannot use ```last monday``` right?

Comment: There is answer for that too. You must check if today is Monday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Day names are [documented](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) as "Moves to the next day of this name" so, at first glance, the output looks correct. `this` doesn't add anything here and is probably just ignored.

Since you want to operate on weeks, you'll need to add `week` to the mix:

```
var_dump(date('r', strtotime('monday this week')));
var_dump(date('r', strtotime('saturday this week')));
var_dump(date('r', strtotime('sunday this week')));
// Edge case (today's day name):
var_dump(date('r', strtotime('friday this week')));
```

```
string(31) "Mon, 16 Aug 2021 00:00:00 +0200"
string(31) "Sat, 21 Aug 2021 00:00:00 +0200"
string(31) "Sun, 22 Aug 2021 00:00:00 +0200"
string(31) "Fri, 20 Aug 2021 00:00:00 +0200"
```

Comment: Yeah, that is working fine but how to I get just day for showing in my frontend or `Y-m-d` for querying database?

Comment: You already do it in the code you've shared: `date('Y-m-d', ...)`. Or perhaps I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I think I will use this ```$monday = Carbon::createFromDate(date('r', strtotime('monday this week', strtotime($date))));``` then for ```'Y-m-d'``` I am able to do this ```$monday->format('Y-m-d')```

Comment: Well... You don't need to convert several times between different formats (string, timestamp, object...)...

Comment: I did that because I want to query database by each day using ```Y-m-d``` and to show date and day in separate places in view. Then I have to create 15 other variables? or do you this is it possible some other way?

Comment: Why do you need the `Sun, 22 Aug 2021 00:00:00 +0200` format at all? I only used it to make values visible in the post since Unix timestamps are unreadable for people. I also can't understand why you think you need to import Carbon. If you are already using Carbon in your project, it's fine, but you didn't mention it in the question.

Comment: Thank you so much, This answer helped me solve my issue, also I did used the string value ```date('d', $monday)```, I think you were mentioning that

Comment: This is the solution I used now ``` $monday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday this week', strtotime($date)));```